# Log file - 1.6 GB - how to push rotation of log file

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, logrotate

How do I push the rotation of a log file.... other_vhosts_access.log is 1.6 GB right now.... the odd thing is that the date on the file is for today, the last rotated file is from 12-12 (a week ago) and is 816 MB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line in your logrotate.conf file (in the appropriate section) like this:

```
size 100M
```

Then run logrotate.  It will force any logs over 100MB in size to be rotated.